# NoMethodError: undefined method `validates_confirmation_of' Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Im getting the above error but dont understand why. Here is the stack trace:

```
    /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/app/models/user.rb:8:in `<class:User>': undefined method `validates_confirmation_of' for User:Class (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/app/data_mapper_setup.rb:6:in `require_relative'
        from /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/app/data_mapper_setup.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/app/app.rb:4:in `require_relative'
        from /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/app/app.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
        from /Users/benrumble/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Full_Stack_Sinatra_App_Skeleton/Skeleton_App_with_user_login:sign_up_and_bcrypt/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1394:in `require'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1394:in `block in requires='
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1394:in `each'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1394:in `requires='
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `block in process_options_into'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `each'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `process_options_into'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /Users/benrumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

and here is the  user.rb model

```
require 'bcrypt'
require 'dm-validations'

class User
  attr_reader :password
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation

  validates_confirmation_of :password

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :email, String

  property :password_digest, String, length: 60

  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end

end
```

I tried with and without 'dm-validations' but it doesnt make a difference.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The problem seems to be in `validates_confirmation_of :password`, `validates_confirmation_of` is a method included in `DataMapper::Resource` but this method is deprecate. Look: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dm-validations/DataMapper/Validations/ValidatesConfirmation

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by moving the

```
include DataMapper::Resource
```

line as the first line after declaring the class.